# Cannot seem to load CCTree database with vim

Tags: vim, cscope

I am trying to use the CCTree plugin for vim, but when I try to add the following line to my vimrc to autoload the cscope database for CCTree every time vim is opened, I get an error. This is the command copied straight from the CCTree website (https://sites.google.com/site/vimcctree/faq):

```
autocmd VimEnter * if filereadable('cscope.out') | CCTreeLoadDB cscope.out | endif
```

The error I get is:

```
Error detected while processing VimEnter Auto commands for "*":
E172: Only one file name allowed:  CCTreeLoadDB cscope.out | endif
```

I would have assumed this would work as it is straight from the CCtree website but I don't know how to debug this as I've barely used/edited my vimrc file. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its seems that `CCTreeLoadDB` think that the `|` and `endif` are parameters to it commands instead of the separator to the `if`.

Wrapping it in a function so that the `if` statement is on multiple line makes the `autocmd` work.

```
function! LoadCCTree()
    if filereadable('cscope.out')
        CCTreeLoadDB cscope.out
    endif
endfunc
autocmd VimEnter * call LoadCCTree()
```

Working one liner that doesn't use a function wrapper. Wrap the `CCTreeLoadDB` in an exec so it doesn't get confused.

```
autocmd VimEnter * if filereadable('cscope.out') | exec "CCTreeLoadDB 'cscope.out'" | endif
```

---

See Ingo Karkat's answer for why `CCTreeLoadDB` does not work with `|`

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you! They really should update their instructions for people like me who have very little experience with using the vimrc file. I went with the function method by the way (for future reference).

Answer (score 1):

You can only chain commands that are defined with `-bar`. If the `:CCTreeLoadDB` command just takes a filename, it would be safe to modify it:

```
:command! -bar ... CCTreeLoadDB ...
```

You could send such a suggestion to the plugin's author. In the meantime, it's best to wrap the command in `:execute`.